# How to validate XForm Constraints in Java Based Web Applications using Orbeon

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We have designed a web application with AngularJS + HTML5 + Spring RESTFul Services. Now I have got a requirement of validating some specific fields in the UI with some of the constraints (XForms). The input to that XForms Constraints will be a XML as usual, the crucial thing here is the XML file is very large and contains lot of data which are required for that XForms.

Can someone tell me from scratch how to implement this and validate the input fields with XForms and show any error if available on the HTML screen?

I have downloaded orbeon, I have taken the XForms example file and replaced my XForms in it and supplied my XML as input. When I run the same I get an output with all the required values and it is validating perfectly. But the problem is I want that to happen on my HTML 5 UI instead of Orbeon UI.

Comment: I fear that I don't understand what you mean by "happen on my HTML 5 UI instead of Orbeon UI". Do you want to embed the form within your HTML page?

Comment: Ebruchez, i have an HTML 5 + AngularJS + J2EE application, Consider i have a field FirstName in my HTML5 page, but the validations need to be applied for that FirstName field will be in xforms as constraints. So what i have to do is to take the value of FIrstName field from HTML Form and then send it to orbeon and get it validated get the response from orbeon and display it in HTML5 from.  If it has error i have display the error. Please let me know whether it make sense or else i can explain more clearly.

Comment: You could create an XForms validation service which run XForms validations on the XML data you send it and returns another XML document with the list of validations that succeeded/failed, but that's a project in itself and it's beyond the scope of StackOverflow to provide all the details.

Comment: Thanks for your time Ebruchez, i'm desperately looking for a solution to this problem. Is there any place where i can find a solution for it, some other forum or from some other team ? Please help me out Ebruchez.

Comment: I don't think you will find a ready-made solution, unfortunately.